# Angularjs. Ng-repeat. Group of radio buttons doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yynswvbo/) is my example.
As a result there is generated two groups of radio buttons. 
But group with properly checked item is only one. 
It works ok, but why needed item in another group is unchecked?

Here is code:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
     <head>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<script>

    var app = angular.module('test', []);


    function test1($scope)
    {
        $scope.test = [1,2,3];

        $scope.generateChartId = function (stn)
        {
            return "chart" + stn;
        };

        $scope.generateRadioOptionName = function (stn)
        {
            return "optionsRadios" + stn;
        };

        $scope.generateRadioOptionId = function (stn, num)
        {
            return "optionsRadio" + stn + num;
        };

    }

</script>


<body ng-app="test">

<div id="example" >
    <div class="box-col row" ng-repeat="stn in [1,2]">

        <div ng-controller="test1">
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{generateRadioOptionName(stn)}}"
                       id="{{generateRadioOptionId(stn,1)}}" checked>
                    XYZ
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{generateRadioOptionName(stn)}}"

                           id="{{generateRadioOptionId(stn,2)}}">
                    ENU
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>


 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `<form>` tag, also your html is a bit "untidy" - you should close `<input>` tags

Working example :

http://jsfiddle.net/michal_taborowski/L77x525s/

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-controller="..."
```

and

```
ng-repeat="..."
```

should swap places.

Comment: Thank you for response! It is not the case, I just experimented and forgot to swap. So, there is something else... http://jsfiddle.net/yynswvbo/1/

Comment: I think you need an array of objects, eg, [{'num': 1, 'val': 'XYZ'}, {'num': 2, 'val': 'ENU'}], and iterate thru this within a single div block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue, and the wierd thing is is that it works with Angular 1.0.2, but as soon as I upgraded to 1.4.8, it stopped working correctly. What I'm hoping the behavior to be is that all the radio groups should have a preset item selected, but what is happening is that only the last group in each panel is being selected

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6q757gh/8/)

This is the html

```
 <body ng-controller="Channels" class="container-fluid">

 <div ng-if="sections===null">
   Loading...
 </div>

 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" ng-if="sections!==null">

     <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in sections | orderBy: 'resourceCode'">

       <div class="panel-heading">
         <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-primary" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"></div>
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#{{getID(item)}}">
           <span class="panel-title" ng-bind="item.resourceCode"></span>
         </a>
       </div>

       <div id="{{getID(item)}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="{'in': isActiveSection(item)}">
       <table class="table">
         <thead>
           <th class="col-md-6">Name</th>
           <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Read</th>
           <th class="col-md-2 text-center">ReadWrite</th>
           <th class="col-md-2 text-center">None</th>
         </thead>       
         <tr ng-repeat="subitem in item.subPrivilegeModels | orderBy: 'resourceCode'">
           <td class="col-md-6"><span ng-bind="subitem.resourceCode"></span></td>
           <td class="col-md-2 text-center">               
             <input type="radio" name="access_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'READ'"/>                 
           </td>
           <td class="col-md-2 text-center radio">
             <input type="radio" name="access_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'READWRITE'"/>
           </td>
           <td class="col-md-2 text-center radio">
             <input type="radio" name="access_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-model="subitem.access" ng-value="'NONE'"/>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tbody>
       </table>
       </div>

     </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: not to worry...managed to solve it using a form element between the sections and changed the naming of the radiobuttons